# Change variable inside async call

Tags: java, android, boolean, okhttp

I am trying to parse the `response` I get from my `OkHttp3Connection` and it always almost always returns me `String` with value `"true"` which is `names[0]` in this example.

Now I try to convert this string to boolean and return `true/false` depending on the response. Now I guess since the `OkHttp3Connection` takes some time it doesnt let the query to finish and returns `false` which is the default value.

What I was trying to say is that this function always returns `false` no matter what String `names[0]` is.

```
public boolean checkIfSongPurhcased(String songName){

    final boolean[] songCheckResult = new boolean[1];

    OkHttp3Connection.doOkHttp3Connection("", Services_Url_class.GET_SONG_PURCHASED, OkHttp3Connection.Request_type.POST, request_data, new OkHttp3Connection.OkHttp3RequestCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String result, String userTag) throws JSONException {
                    JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray data = jsonResult.getJSONArray("data");
                    if(data != null) {
                        String[] names = new String[data.length()];
                        for(int i = 0 ; i < data.length() ; i++) {
                            JSONArray arr = data.getJSONArray(i);
                            JSONObject dataObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
                            Iterator<String> keys = dataObj.keys();
                            names[i] = dataObj.getString(keys.next());
                        }

                        //names[0] is "true"
                        songCheckResult[0] = Boolean.parseBoolean(names[0]);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(String error, String userTag) {
                    System.out.println("songy" + error);
                }
            }
    );

    //always returns false
    return songCheckResult[0];
```

How can I make it so if `names[0] is "true"` it would give me true.

Comment: FYI, **doOkHttp3Connection** is an asynchronous call, that is the reason your method always returns false which is the default value of songCheckResult[0].

Comment: @KrishnaSharma how can I get the value from there then?

Comment: to do that you can create a listener interface, see the answer post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the listener/callback.

First create callback interface like below

```
public interface OnQueryResultCallback{
   void onQueryResult(String songName, boolean status);
}
```

Then pass listener/callback to your method, here is the modified method.

```
public void checkIfSongPurhcased(final String songName, final OnQueryResultCallback listener){
    OkHttp3Connection.doOkHttp3Connection("", Services_Url_class.GET_SONG_PURCHASED, OkHttp3Connection.Request_type.POST, request_data, new OkHttp3Connection.OkHttp3RequestCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String result, String userTag) throws JSONException {
                    JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray data = jsonResult.getJSONArray("data");
                    if(data != null) {
                        String[] names = new String[data.length()];
                        for(int i = 0 ; i < data.length() ; i++) {
                            JSONArray arr = data.getJSONArray(i);
                            JSONObject dataObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
                            Iterator<String> keys = dataObj.keys();
                            names[i] = dataObj.getString(keys.next());
                        }

                        //names[0] is "true"
                        boolean status = Boolean.parseBoolean(names[0]);
                        listener.onQueryResult(songName,status);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(String error, String userTag) {
                    System.out.println("songy" + error);
                    listener.onQueryResult(songName,false);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Then call checkIfSongPurhcased like below

```
checkIfSongPurhcased("songName", new OnQueryResultCallback(){
   public void onQueryResult(String songName, boolean status){
        if(status){
          // do something on success
        }else{
         // do something on failure
        }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use getBoolean() rather than getString().

For Eg: `names[i] = dataObj.getBoolean(keys.next());`

Comment: This won't really change much since it wont reach out of the call async call